# Como agregar Columnas a datagrid dentro de userControl

Tags: c#, wpf

tengo un UserControl que dentro tiene un datagrid, la idea es que cuando se use dicho control se debe especificar que columnas se agregaran, ¿como puedo hacer esto?

Gracias desde ya.
Saludos.

Edito 1:

He intentado crear una DependencyProperty en mi UserControl

```
    #region PROPIEDADES
    public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> ColumnCollection
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)GetValue(ColumnCollectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnCollectionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnCollectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>), typeof(BusquedaControl), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> { }));
    #endregion
```

Este es el metodo constructor de UserControl

```
    public BusquedaControl()
    {
        ColumnCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>();

        ColumnCollection.CollectionChanged += (x, y) =>
        {
            datagrid.Columns.Clear();

            foreach (var column in this.ColumnCollection)
            {
                datagrid.Columns.Add(column);
            }
        };

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Asi uso mi UserControl en una GUI.

```
    <ctrl:BusquedaControl x:Name="ctrl__busqueda_control">
        <ctrl:BusquedaControl.ColumnCollection>
            <ctrl:DataGridTextColumnControl Header="NIVEL" Width="Auto" x:Name="NIVEL" Binding="{Binding NIVEL}"/>
            <ctrl:DataGridTextColumnControl Header="PERFIL" Width="*" x:Name="DESCRIPCION" Binding="{Binding DESCRIPCION}"/>
        </ctrl:BusquedaControl.ColumnCollection>
    </ctrl:BusquedaControl>
```

Sin embargo no puedo establecer los nombres porque me marca un el siguiente error.

> No se puede establecer el valor del atributo Name 'NIVEL' en el
> elemento 'DataGridTextColumn'. 'DataGridTextColumn' está dentro del
> ámbito del elemento 'BusquedaControl', que ya tenía un nombre
> registrado cuando se definió en otro ámbito. Línea 12, posición 77.

Gracias.

Comment: Y que otras cosas tiene el user control? deberias exponer publicamente todas las propiedades de la grilla.. no suena a una buena idea.... tal vez, no sea tu mejor solucion?

Comment: El control tiene muchos controles dentro (es un control que usare en muchas interfaces), mi problema ahora es enlazar las columnas.

Comment: Piensa en tu control como una clase, simplemente hazle un GETTER (un acceso de tipo public) a tu DataGrid o al ItemsSource de tu DataGrid, y siendo público puedes manipularlo como si estuviera en la misma clase desde donde quieres hacerlo.